# Cannot find symbol error Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Hi i am new to Java and i am writting a simple programm that will emulate a diving competition. I use NetBeans and i cannot find out why it gives me this error.
The code is this :

```
package agoneskataduseon;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AgonesKataduseon {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      int numAth, numJud, numDiv;
      System.out.print("Give the number of the athletes in the competition : ");
      numAth = input.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Give the number of the judges : ");
      numJud = input.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Give the numbe rof dives : ");
      numDiv = input.nextInt();
      DivingCompetition game = new Diving Competition(numAth, numJud, numDiv);
  }
}
```

The  DivingCompetition class(it is not finished) :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DivingCompetition {
    int numa;
    int numj;
    int numd;
    Athlete[] arr1 = new Athlete[12];
    Athlete[] arr2 = new Athlete[12];

    public DivingCompetition(int numAthletes, int numJudges, int numDives){
        numa = numAthletes;
        numj = numJudges;
        numd = numDives;
    }

    public void readAthletesName(){
        String nam;
        int i=0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(i < numa){
            System.out.print("Give the name of athlete num "+(i+1)+" : ");
            nam = input.nextLine();
            arr1[i] = new Athlete(nam);
            i++;
        }
    }

    public void runCompetition(){
        int i=0;
        Dive dv = new Dive(numj);
        while(i<12){
           arr1[i].addDive(dv);
        }
   }
}
```

And for the record the Athlete class:

```
public class Athlete {
        String names;
        Dive[] arrayd = new Dive[6]; 
        double fullScore;
        int point;

    public Athlete(String name){
        names = name;
        fullScore = 0;
        point = 0;
    }

    public void addDive(Dive dive){
        arrayd[point] = dive;
        fullScore = fullScore + arrayd[point].computeScore();
        point++;
    }
}
```

I would also give you the Dive class but i dont see the point of doing that

NetBeans is giving me an error in the main function :
Cannot find symbol
        Symbol: class DivingCompetition
        location: class AgonesKataduseon

And my question is why it gives me this error?
This problem also happens if i try to make an object of Athlete or Dive inside the main function

Comment: I think you have to import the class. Try `Ctrl-Shift-I`.  Source: https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/usersguide/shortcuts-80.pdf

Comment: Because `DivingCompetition` isn't in the same package.

Comment: I tried the Ctrl-Shift-I method but it says nothing to fix in import statements.  Can you sugggest me another solution? i am new to NetBeans and i am not used as to how it works

Comment: I think i found the problem. So it appears that i have written the classes in the default package and not in the right one......i feel so stupid you cant imagine how long ive been looking for a solution....

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans will try to help and give you suggestions to fix your code if you ask it to. All you have to do is to place the cursor on the line where the problem is and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: Fix Code]

It actually gives you this keyboard shortcut at that bottom of the error message when you hover over the erroneous statement.

See the [Code Assistance](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/editor-codereference.html#hints-tofix) page in the manual for more info.